# How can I handle this string concatenation in C in a reusable way

Tags: c, strings, file-handling

I've been writing a small C application that operates on files, and I've found that I have been copy+pasting this code around my functions:

```
char fullpath[PATH_MAX];
fullpath[0] = '\0';
strcat(fullpath, BASE_PATH);
strcat(fullpath, subdir);
strcat(fullpath, "/");
strcat(fullpath, filename);

// do something with fullpath...
```

Is there a better way? The first thought that comes to mind is to create a macro but I'm sure this is a common problem in C, and I'm wondering how others have solve it.

Comment: `sprintf(fullpath, "%s%s/%s", BASE_PATH, subdir, filename)`?  Besides being less wordy, it'd also resolve your Schlemiel the Painter issue.  :P

Comment: @cHao I rarely program in C, but isn't the printf family of functions unsafe (as in, undefined behavior if you screw up)?

Comment: @Doval: Nearly everything in C can cause undefined behavior if you screw up.  `strcat` isn't any safer, really, except for the fixed argument list.

Comment: @cHao Thanks, sprintf looks like the most straightforward solution (also thanks for the "Schlemiel the Painter" reference)

Comment: @cHao I'm not suggesting `strcat`, but surely there has to be a less error-prone alternative? It seems pretty easy to me to screw up the format string or have a mismatch between the format string and the arguments. You could write a function that takes a buffer (+ its size) and an array of strings (+ its size) which ensures it won't go out of the buffer's bounds. Such a function can only go wrong if you don't keep track of the size of the arrays (at which point it doesn't matter which method you use for concatenation).

Comment: @Doval: It's a bit harder to screw up with a known, relatively small set of strings, though.  :)  Sticking them in an array and calling some function would add more complexity.  As for the buffer, there's `snprintf` if you think the string might end up too big for the buffer.

Comment: @Doval: Gcc and clang both support type-checking `printf` and `scanf`-family functions and any custom functions that forward their arguments to these (with a special annotation).

Answer (score 2):

Reusable for a function like the one you describe means several things:

- Doesn't assume the input is valid.
- Uses sane defaults.
- Prevents buffer overruns.
- Returns some indication of success or failure.

In your case:

```
#define BASE_PATH "/path/to/wherever"
bool build_path(char *dest, size_t size, char *subdir, char *filename)
{
    // Don't assume the input is valid
    if ( (dest == NULL) || (size < 1) || (filename == NULL) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make no subdir work  (sane default behavior)
    if ( subdir == NULL ) {
        subdir = "";
    }

    // Prevent buffer overruns by using a safe formatting function
    size_t stored = snprintf(dest, size, BASE_PATH "/%s/%s", subdir, filename);

    // Returns success (true) if the path fit the buffer
    return ((stored+1) <= size);
}


char fullpath[PATH_MAX];
if ( ! build_path(fullpath, sizeof(fullpath), "foo/bar", "baz") ) {
   // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Should `snprintf()` return -1 (encoding error), this function mistakenly returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

How about passing the address of `fullpath`, `subdir`, and `filename` into a function and have that function concatenate all of the strings for you?

Something to the effect of:

```
void main(...)
{
    char fullpath[PATH_MAX];
    memset(fullpath, 0x00, PATH_MAX); //note: probably wrong syntax for memset
    ...
    ConcatPath(&fullpath, subdir, filename);
}

ConcatPath(char *fullpath, char *subdir, char *filename)
{
    strcat(fullpath, BASE_PATH);  //note need some casting magic here to reference
    strcat(fullpath, subdir);     // fullpath & other strings correctly.
    strcat(fullpath, "/");
    strcat(fullpath, filename);
}
```

Comment: (technically, `memset(fullpath, 0, PATH_MAX * sizeof(char))`, but assuming that a char is 1 byte wide it should work anyway)

Comment: @amon `sizeof(char)` is always 1, no matter how many bits there are in it

Comment: @amon Does C not guarantee that a char is a byte?  (I know C++ does...)

Comment: @cHao According to C99, the `sizeof` operator returns the width in bytes, but `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. We can therefore deduce that a char is always one byte wide (and indeed, C defines a byte as an adressable unit that can hold a char. The confusing part is that a char must be at least 8 bits wide, which means that C's concept of a byte could be different from a hardware byte on exotic architectures). In my previous comment, I was being as vague as possible because I didn't want to accidentally state something that would actually be undefined.

Comment: This will break badly if the arguments point to strings whose combined length plus that of BASE_PATH, the slash and the NUL at the end exceeds the size of the array.

Comment: @GlenH7:  [Easily remedied](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/242779/20756).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, as a professional programmer, you *must not* write code like that. You *must* either write your own path concatenation function, or use the one provided by the platform.

If it's Windows you should use the `_makepath` function. For greater safety, use the `_makepath_s` function. It will be more careful than you are. I'm sure Posix has something similar.

If you must write your own, simple concatenation is just not good enough. You need to check for proper handling of delimiters, trailing slash on directories, leading period on extensions, null arguments and all that stuff. The good news is that if you do it once it's done.

In the more general case of concatenating strings, you are very hampered by your apparent decision to stick with C rather than C++. I would again recommend writing your own function with variable arguments (`vararg`) and using `strcat_s()` for security. Something like:

```
bool strcat_multi_s(char *destination, size_t maxlength, ...); // return false on overflow
```

I leave the coding as an exercise for the reader.